# How to support JS ES5/ES6 prototype as well as static extensions module

Tags: javascript, module

I am coming up to speed on JS ES5/ES6 modules, how to test them, package them, etc. I am somewhat familiar with the module exports feature that node and npm wants, for instance, but in this case I am adding functionality onto JS prototypes as well as static methods on those base "types" (classes).

Just for example,

```
Array.prototype.suchAndSuch = ...
```

Or,

```
Array.thisThatAndTheOther = ...
```

Not necessarily, `Array`, per se, but you get the idea, hopefully.

I'm unclear as to how that necessarily gets *included*, *imported*, or otherwise *"required"* for use during a unit test?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Extending a global object (which, just as a reminder, is [still considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1048572)!) basically is a side-effect of running the code and does not produce any new value to export. Your module would therefore have no `export` declaration, and to include it (declare the dependency) you would not import anything into a local binding, but rather just use

```
import './array_extensions';
```